# RLink load xlsx package

Tags: rlink, r

I'm trying to load the xlsx package in RLink (M 12.1, W10).

This works fine:

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR[
"RHomeLocation"->"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.6.3",
"RVersion"->"3.6.3",
"NativeLibLocation"->"C:\\Users\\ai\\Documents\\R\\win-library\\3.6\\rJava\\jri\\x64"
]
```

I can load some libraries:

```
REvaluate["library('xts')"]
```

But loading xlsx library fails:

```
REvaluate["install.packages('xlsx')"]
REvaluate["library('xlsx')"]
```

With the following error

````
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'xlsx', details:
  call: .jcall("java.lang.System", "S", "getProperty", "java.version")
  error: RcallMethod: cannot determine object class```


What am I doing wrong? How can I make it work?
````

Comment: Have you tried `ExternalEvaluate`? It supports R already

Comment: @swish Isn't hat built in RLink as well?

Comment: @Szabolcs Just thought maybe it would do something differently. But actually not, I've reproduced the same error with both `REvaluate` and `ExternalEvaluate` on macOs.